# Drawing node on top of the others in HBox

Tags: javafx, hbox

I am looking for a way to draw a node on top of the neighbouring ones in a HBox. Default behaviour means it is drawn on top of the previous one, but that also means the next one is drawn on top of it. For other containers, one could use the Node.toFront(), but changing the position of the node in the list containing a HBox's children also changes the actual position in the HBox, which is unwanted behaviour in my case. I appreciate any help, thank you.

EDIT:
The overlapping occurs when applying a DropShadow effect on an Ellipse and wrapping them in a StackPane along with a Text. It looks like the effect has a weird interaction with the HBox, as it works as intended without it. After adding the effect, it allocates more horizontal space for the ellipse, but not enough to cover the  margins of the effect. Also, when clicking anywhere in the whole right half of the black rectangle, the mouse click is dispatched to the stackPane event handler, not to the rectangle's.

[This happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEdOs.png)

Comment: Usually a `HBox` draws the children to different areas. How do you make them overlap?

Comment: First set a standard size for the `HBox`,then play with the size and padding of every children.What do you want to make?A picture will be appreciated cause doing that we can provide code.

Comment: @fabian edited to add more information. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

In VBox and HBox, the Node.toFront() and Node.toBack() functions will change the layout, so they are not usable. If you are using JavaFX 9+,you can use the viewOrder commands to change the rendering order of the Node in its Parent:

```
Node.getViewOrder()
Node.setViewOrder()
```

The default value of viewOrder is 0, so setting it to -1 will render it above all others. You can customize this to get specific orders. It also has a CSS property -fx-view-order.